# Looking for a solution to annotate image with a Polygon in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to make a very simple image annotation where the user annotates and image and adds a comment to that annotation and save it to my database using jQuery, PHP and Ajax.

I have no clue about how to do it and I'm looking for some guidance, not actual code.

I found the Annotorious library and used it and it's really what I want but it is limited in the sense that I can't paint the polygons.

Would someone please give some guidance on this?

Comment: I assume you want to put a polygon on your image and then draw the comment in the polygon. You can do this in a bitmap, but it is probably better to render the image on the web, then place a polygon/text vector element on top. You could do this with an SVG image.